# How to disable button in datagridrow in wpf programmatically

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I had placed datagrid populating data from database.

Now I had kept button in all row using datagridcolumntemplate and datatemplate

I want to disable button of last column for first two rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a View Model to wrap the database data into Objects and add an extra property to them: IsVisible.

Then inside your data template you can set the binding of the Button to :

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=MyObject.IsVisible, 
        Converter={BooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}"/>
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but at least you don't mess with code behind. Also, I'm not sure if you can get the *Row Collection* of your grid using another approach.

HTH